# How do you see if a key includes a value and return the key up 2 levels? Alexa/JS

Tags: javascript, json

I want to see if a category is in a pack, and if it is, return that pack name.

So if my string was 'Pack1category1', I want to return 'pack1'.

How could I go about doing this?

```
{
    "paidTier": {
        "categoryPacks": {
            "pack1": {
                "categories": [
                    "Pack1category1",
                    "Pack1category2",
                    "Pack1category3",
                    "Pack1category4",
                    "Pack1category5",
                    "Pack1category6"
                ]
            },
            "pack2": {
                "categories": [
                    "Pack2category1",
                    "Pack2category2",
                    "Pack2category3",
                    "Pack2category4",
                    "Pack2category5",
                    "Pack2category6"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Something like this:

```
var string = 'Pack1category1'
//Loop through paidTier and find string
return 'pack1';
```

or

```
var string = 'Pack2category5'
//Loop through paidTier and find string
return 'pack2';
```

I've been at this for at least 10 hours and every method I've tried has failed. Please help! lol

Comment: _I've been at this for at least 10 hours and every method I've tried has failed_. Could you include one of these tries?

Comment: I have tried using a for loop to iterate through the object and I can successfully grab the categories themselves. I can also grab the packs. I just am having trouble linking the two together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mentioned you where using a `for` loop to traverse the object, I give you an approach using that way. We going to use [for ... in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) to traverse the `paidTier.cateroryPacks` object and [Array.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check if the inner `categories` array includes the searched string.

```js
const data = {"paidTier":{"categoryPacks":{"pack1":{"categories":["Pack1category1","Pack1category2","Pack1category3","Pack1category4","Pack1category5","Pack1category6"]},"pack2":{"categories":["Pack2category1","Pack2category2","Pack2category3","Pack2category4","Pack2category5","Pack2category6"]}}}};

function getPack(catPacks, str)
{
    for (const pack in catPacks)
    {
        if (catPacks[pack].categories.includes(str))
            return pack;
    }

    return "No Pack Found!";
}

let catPacks = data.paidTier.categoryPacks;
console.log("Result for Pack1category1:", getPack(catPacks, "Pack1category1"));
console.log("Result for Pack2category5:", getPack(catPacks, "Pack2category5"));
console.log("Result for Pack3category5:", getPack(catPacks, "Pack3category5"));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Comment: This method works wonderfully with the program flow I have already. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**Object.keys**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [**filter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [**some**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

- First get `categoryPacks` from original data
- For each key's of `categoryPacks` we check for categories property if it includes `keyToFind` than we include it in final output else ignore it

```js
let data = {"paidTier": {"categoryPacks": {"pack1": {"categories": ["Pack1category1","Pack1category2","Pack1category3","Pack1category4","Pack1category5","Pack1category6"]},"pack2": {"categories": ["Pack2category1","Pack2category2","Pack2category3","Pack2category4","Pack2category5","Pack2category6"]}}}}


let getKey = (keyToFind) => {
  let {categoryPacks} = data.paidTier
  let foundKeys = Object.keys(categoryPacks).filter(key => {
        return categoryPacks[key].categories.some(val => val === keyToFind)
  })
  return foundKeys
}

console.log(getKey('Pack1category1'))
console.log(getKey('Pack2category5'))
console.log(getKey('Pack2category22'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
// assume `json` is your input object
var desiredCategory = 'Pack1category1';
var packCategories = json.paidTier.categoryPacks

var pack = Object.keys(packCategories).find(pack => packCategories[pack].categories.includes(desiredCategory))
console.log(pack) // 'pack1'
```

Comment: @code-maniac his answer will return a list of any packs that match the category, mine will only return the first value.

Answer (score 1):

```
const packages = {
    "paidTier": {
        "categoryPacks": {
            "pack1": {
                "categories": [
                    "Pack1category1",
                    "Pack1category2",
                    "Pack1category3",
                    "Pack1category4",
                    "Pack1category5",
                    "Pack1category6"
                ]
            },
            "pack2": {
                "categories": [
                    "Pack2category1",
                    "Pack2category2",
                    "Pack2category3",
                    "Pack2category4",
                    "Pack2category5",
                    "Pack2category6"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}

const findPack = (categoryName) => Object.keys(packages.paidTier.categoryPacks).find(packName => 
  packages.paidTier.categoryPacks[packName].categories.includes(categoryName)
)

findPack('Pack2category1') // => "pack2"
```